# How to create twiny label on multiple plots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have created 3x3 gridplot using the code:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Now I want to plot two functions in each plot, where the x-axis is the same but the y axis is different for the two functions (i.e. each subplot should have two y-axes). I have tried to use the twinx method to declare the second plot function

```
fig, axarr2 = plt.subplots(3,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axarr2[0,0] = axarr[0,0].twinx()
axarr2[0,1] = axarr[0,1].twinx()
axarr2[0,2] = axarr[0,2].twinx()
axarr2[1,0] = axarr[1,0].twinx()
axarr2[1,1] = axarr[1,1].twinx()
axarr2[1,2] = axarr[1,2].twinx()
axarr2[2,0] = axarr[2,0].twinx()
axarr2[2,1] = axarr[2,1].twinx()
axarr2[2,2] = axarr[2,2].twinx()
```

But this way, I am creating an extra figure, which is not what I want to do.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then don't create a new figure.

```
axarr2 = np.empty_like(axarr)
axarr2[0, 0] = axarr[0,0].twinx()
```

Answer (score -1):

As Goyo suggested, it was unnecessary to use the version of my suggested solution. I used his input to implement a more sustainable solution.